# Setting a variable of a javascript from an other, in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I have the following problem:

In file (let a.js be) I have:

```
var kindofdisplay ;
```

In an other file ( let b.js be)
I get the information to set *kindofdisplay*.
Now, I would like to set **kindofdisplay** from file b.js so that when a.js is executed it will be able to process the variable in a correct way.

Many thanks

Comment: All the js files that are loaded on the same page are part of the same script, so it doesn't realy matter where you set the variable.

Comment: don't declare the variable again in b.js..then it will work the way you  wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Raja pointed out. If you can access the kindofdisplay variable on b.js, you can change it. You just need to take care not to declare it again.

You can try give a default value like:

```
var kindofdisplay='none';
```

And check if that's the value the variable has when on b.js. If it's not, you are probably declaring it again.

Comment: Ok, it works.
In your opinion Is this the best way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the two javascript files on different web pages, you could always set the variable as a cookie (providing you don't need it to be secure).

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) about cookies.

Another way to do this would be to put the script that defines the function for setting the variable in one file, link it to both pages that you need the variable to exist in and call the function on each page.

Of course, as a couple of people have already explained, if you're using the two javascript files on the same page, there's no need to do this - just ensure that the variable has the appropriate scope.